# No specs found while running protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

STEPS:
1.protractor .\conf\conf.js

o/p:

```
> PS D:\CHOR-3823\LatestAutomation\PROJECTS\EVAutomation> protractor .\conf\conf.js
[18:12:11] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[18:12:11] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53625/devtools/browser/6885cfd9-3e30-42c9-b866-cbc7a01db67d
[29324:12112:0828/181212.692:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(208)] [18:12:12.693] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1164 RequestRadioAccessAsync failed: RadioAccessStatus::DeniedByUserWill not be able to change radio power.
User Name Locator is : //input[@placeholder='Username']
User Pass Locator is : //input[@placeholder='Password']
User Sign IN Locator is : Sign In
Started
Suite started: Login test whose full description is: Login test
Suitename is:Login test
directory created..
suitename is:login
Directory path is:logs\2020\8\28\Login test\login_20200828124213.log
Log Folder Link : ftp:\1.1.1.8\mnt.\logs\2020\8\28\Login test\login_20200828124213.log
myLogger....


No specs found
Finished in 0.009 seconds

priting json data....
Email report<html.html> saved successfully..
[18:12:13] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
```

Note:-it is saying no specs found . but actually its going inside the specs and it is printing some message from the page directory which is used by the spec file.but it is not able to call any method of that page file and just after that it is coming out of execution and saying no spects found.

Please find the conf.js code:

```
    require("@babel/register")({
      presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
      plugins: [["@babel/transform-runtime"]]
    });
    var jasmineReporters = require("jasmine-reporters");
    var htmlReporter = require("protractor-html-reporter-2");
    var jasmineSpecReporter = require("jasmine-spec-reporter");
    var screenshots = require('protractor-take-screenshots-on-demand');
    var fs = require("fs-extra");
    var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
    var EmailTemplate = require("email-templates").EmailTemplate;
    const Logger = require("../utils/logger.js");
    var ejs = require("ejs");
    var fs = require("fs");
    var xml2js = require("xml2js");
    exports.config = {
      framework: "jasmine",
      directConnect: true,
      // suites: {
      //loginswilite : "src/testcases/sweliteLogin/*.js"
      //DeviceSWeLite : "src/testcases/Devicelogin/*.js"  
      //DevicePageGUI : "src/testcases/DeviceGUI/*.js"
      //RebootDevice: "src/testcases/Rebootdevice/*.js"  
      //Run_Health_Report : "src/testcases/HealthReport/*.js"
      //Delete_Undelete_Device : "src/testcases/DeleteAndUndelete/*.js"
      //Backup_and_Restore_Config : "src/testcases/BackupAndRestore_Config/*.js"
      // login_spec :"../tests/login_spec/*.js"
      //Bulk_Add_user : "src/testcases/BulkAdduser/*.js"    
      //login: ["src/testcases/login/*.js","src/testcases/Add_collection_move_device/*.js"]
      //sanity: ["src/testcases/login/*.js", "src/testcases/collection/*.js"]
      //src/testcases/DeleteAndUndelete/*.js
      specs: [
        'D:\\CHOR-3823\\LatestAutomation\\PROJECTS\\EVAutomation\\tests\\login_spec.js'
      ],
      // },
      SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
      capabilities: {
        //browserName: "firefox",
        //acceptInsecureCerts: true,
        browserName: "chrome",
        chromeOptions: {
          args: ["--start-maximized", "--ignore-certificate-errors"]
        }
      },
      // Options to be passed to Jasmine-node.
      jasmineNodeOpts: {
        onComplete: null,
        // If true, display spec names.
        isVerbose: false,
        // If true, print colors to the terminal.
        showColors: true,
        // If true, include stack traces in failures.
        includeStackTrace: true,
        // Default time to wait in ms before a test fails.
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 1200000
      },
      onPrepare: function () {
        "use strict";
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        // jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new HtmlReporter({
        //     baseDirectory: 'reports'
        //     }).getJasmine2Reporter());
        browser.timeStamp = new Date()
          .toISOString()
          .replace(/T/, "") // replace T with a space
          .replace(/\..+/, "")
          .split("-")
          .join("")
          .split(":")
          .join("");
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
          new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
            consolidateAll: true,
            savePath: "./reports/xml",
            filePrefix: "xmlresults"
          })
        );
        screenshots.browserNameJoiner = ' - ';
        screenshots.screenShotDirectory = 'target/screenshots';
        screenshots.createDirectory();
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter({
          suiteStarted: function (result) {
            browser.suiteName = result.fullName;
            console.log(
              "Suite started: " +
              result.description +
              " whose full description is: " +
              result.fullName
            );
          },
          specStarted: function (result) {
            //Logger initialiation for test case
            browser.testcaseName = result.description;
            browser.logger = new Logger();
            browser.logDir = browser.logger.getLogDir();
            browser.logFolderLink = browser.logger.getLogFolderLink();
          },
          specDone: function (result) {
            console.log("Test Completed:" + result.fullName);
            if (result.status == "failed") {
              browser.logger.result(result.status.toUpperCase());
              result.failedExpectations.forEach(element => {
                browser.logger.error(element.stack);
              });
            }
            browser.logger.result(result.status);
            browser.getCapabilities().then(function (caps) {
              var browserName = caps.get("browserName");
              browser.takeScreenshot().then(function (png) {
                var stream = fs.createWriteStream(
                  "./reports/" +
                  browserName +
                  "/screenshots/" +
                  browserName +
                  "-" +
                  result.fullName +
                  ".png"
                );
                stream.write(Buffer.from(png, "base64"));
                stream.end();
              });
            });
          }
        });
      },
      onComplete: function () {
        var browserName, browserVersion;
        var capsPromise = browser.getCapabilities();
        capsPromise.then(function (caps) {
          browserName = caps.get("browserName");
          browserVersion = caps.get("version");
          platform = caps.get("platform");
          testConfig = {
            reportTitle: "Protractor Test Execution Report",
            outputPath: "./reports/",
            outputFilename: "ProtractorTestReport",
            screenshotPath: browserName + "/screenshots",
            testBrowser: browserName,
            browserVersion: browserVersion,
            modifiedSuiteName: false,
            screenshotsOnlyOnFailure: false,
            testPlatform: platform
          };
          new htmlReporter().from("./reports/xml/xmlresults.xml", testConfig);
        });
        var parser = new xml2js.Parser({ mergeAttrs: true, explicitArray: false });
        var jsonData = "";
        var myresult;
        var xmlData = fs.readFileSync("./reports/xml/xmlresults.xml", "utf8");
        my_data = parser.parseString(xmlData, function (err, result) {
          console.log("priting json data....");
          //jsonData = JSON.stringify(result);
          myresult = result;
        });
        var htmlContent = fs.readFileSync("./reports/template.ejs", "utf8");
        var htmlRenderized = ejs.render(htmlContent, {
          filename: "./reports/template.ejs",
          jsonobject: myresult,
          timestamp: browser.timeStamp,
          logDir: browser.logDir
        });
        //console.log(htmlRenderized);
        fs.writeFile("./reports/html.html", htmlRenderized, function (err) {
          if (err) return console.log(err);
          console.log("Email report<html.html> saved successfully.. ");
        });
       
      }
    };
```

Please find the content of login_spec.js :

```
    let inputPara = require('../object_repository/inputPageOR.json')
    let loginpage = require('../pages/loginpage')
    let Logger = require('../utils/logger.js')
    describe('Login test', function () {
      /*  "use strict";
        let logger;
        beforeEach(function () {
            logger = new Logger();
            logger.setcurrentFile(__filename);
            logger.info("Testcase :" + " " + browser.testcaseName + " " + "started");
            logger.info(browser.logger.getLogDir() + "/" + browser.suiteName + "/" + browser.testcaseName + "/" + browser.timeStamp + '.' + 'log');
            logger.info(browser.logger.getLogFolderLink() + "/" + browser.suiteName + "/" + browser.testcaseName + "/" + browser.timeStamp + '.' + 'log');
            logger.info("Before Each: Opening Login Page");
          });  */
        it('login', function () {
            let url = inputPara.openPage.url;
            let userName = inputPara.login.username;
            let password = inputPara.login.password;
            // browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
           // logger.info("opening EV GUI");
            loginpage.get(url.toString());
            loginpage.userName(userName.toString());
            loginpage.userPassword(password.toString());
            loginpage.buttonClick();
            browser.sleep(2000)
        });
    });
```

please find the content of loginpage file:

```
    let objRepo = require("../object_repository/commonPageOR.json");
    let loginpage = function () {
        //Fetching data from Json file for Locator
        let uname= objRepo.loginPageValue.usernameInput
        let upass= objRepo.loginPageValue.passwordInput
        let uclick= objRepo.loginPageValue.submitButton
        console.log("User Name Locator is : " + uname);
        console.log("User Pass Locator is : " + upass);
        console.log("User Sign IN Locator is : " + uclick);
        let userName_input = element(by.xpath(uname.toString()));
        let userPassword_input = element(by.xpath(upass.toString()));
        let signInbutton = element(by.partialButtonText(uclick.toString()));
        
         this.get =  function (url) {
            try{
            browser.get(url);
             
            }
            catch(err){
                console.log(err.stack());
            }
        }
        this.userName =  function (userName) {
            try{
            userName_input.clear();
            userName_input.sendKeys(userName);
           
            }
            catch(err){
                console.log(err.stack());
            }
        }
        this.userPassword =  function (password) {
            try{
            userPassword_input.clear();
             userPassword_input.sendKeys(password);
             
            }
            catch(err){
                console.log(err.stack());
            }
        }
        this.buttonClick =  function () {
            try{
            signInbutton.click();
            
            }
            catch(err){
                console.log(err.stack());
            }
        }
    }
    module.exports = new loginpage();
```

please find the directory structure:

[Directory structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RA0Xi.png)

Answer (score 0):

For me this seems like something wrong with specs in config file

```
specs: [
        'D:\\CHOR-3823\\LatestAutomation\\PROJECTS\\EVAutomation\\tests\\login_spec.js'
      ],
```

Try giving relative path like

```
specs: [
        '../tests/login_spec/js'
      ],
```

That should work